# code::blocks doesn't save my settings as default

Tags: codeblocks

I'm a newbie to `code::blocks`. I have just installed it on my `ubuntu desktop` and made some changes to its settings such as change `default font size` , change `caret's color`, and some more things in `settings -> editor`. But when I close `code::blocks` I see message on a pop-up window `the perspective code blocks default has changed do you want to save it?`I was not able to save my perspective irrespective of clicking `yes` in the dialogue box.

I also uninstalled and re-installed it but the problem still persists. I searched all over the internet but can't find solution to my problem. I think I've loosen my mind now. Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a permission issue. Type `chmod -R 777 ./.config/codeblocks/` in `terminal` and you are all set :)